# Azure Data Factory Data Flow Source Column Differ In Case

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

From one vendor I have a textual source column titled THE_ID

From another vendor the same column has been labelled  The_Id

My data flow is breaking because of this difference. How can I enforce case insensitivity within the data flow?

Comment: Not sure about changing case sensitivity, but you can use either a Select or Derived Column Activity to assign a new name with the proper case.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and sample input output?

Comment: The issue specifically is the incoming text file has capitalized a column name that is breaking the source shape in the data flow.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be the input schema on the source dataset is not capable of being defined as case-insensitive.

A long term solution is going to be

1. Enforce vendor compliance to provide upper case column names.
2. Introduce a pre-processor to force column headers to uppercase.